# Software store/market for Windows with freeware?

Tags: windows, software-update

Phone software store/markets not only offers new apps, but also manage updates. I know there are many software downloaders like Ninite that has some of these features, but I haven't seen any way of keeping my apps updated. Most of the app I use check for updates, but ask me to go to their site, download and run the updates manually.

Is there a software that could help me with this?

(In Ubuntu you have apt-get, aptitude, Synaptic and Software Center that do this)

Comment: It would be nice to have something like "Windows Market", an official professional solution to this by Microsoft, which would provide the apps, updates, and thanks to Microsoft it would cooperate with Windows correctly. But unfortunately, Microsoft isn't interested in free apps (unlike Google).

Comment: @AlKepp Have you seen the Windows 8 Developer preview? Your wishes are fulfilled: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2011/12/06/announcing-the-new-windows-store.aspx

Comment: [RuckZuck](http://ruckzuck.tools/) is a solution - all other alternatives listed there: http://alternativeto.net/software/ruckzuck

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is [**Secunia PSI**](http://secunia.com/) (Personal Software Inspector) for *managing patches and updates* on already installed programs:

> The Secunia PSI is a free security tool designed to detect vulnerable and out-dated programs and plug-ins which expose your PC to attacks. Attacks exploiting vulnerable programs and plug-ins are rarely blocked by traditional anti-virus and are therefore increasingly "popular" among criminals.
>
> The only solution to block these kind of attacks is to apply security updates, commonly referred to as patches. Patches are offered free-of-charge by most software vendors, however, finding all these patches is a tedious and time consuming task. Secunia PSI automates this and alerts you when your programs and plug-ins require updating to stay secure.

*Not my program*, but have used in the past, and it does a pretty good job of finding software that needs to be updated...It's worth a try!

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to install new software using this software package, instead of updating already-installed software?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I don't believe so.

Answer (score 3):

I found [Windows-Get](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windows-get) but there are no new releases since 2007

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 will have the [Windows Store](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304065723/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2011/12/06/announcing-the-new-windows-store.aspx), which will only deploy Metro style apps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Milouz Market](http://market.milouz.com)  is a free software manager for Windows XP/Vista/7/8 32/64bits. It allows you to download and install from a pre-populated list of commonly used software. In addition, as it is maintained actively be the online community, you will be notified if an update is available.