# Is there anything like the Ubuntu Software Center for Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software store/market for Windows with freeware?](https://superuser.com/questions/275815/software-store-market-for-windows-with-freeware)
>   [App store for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/307983/app-store-for-windows)

Is there anything like the Ubuntu Software Center for Windows (i. e., a software application that makes it easy to install software, and also manages package dependencies?)

Comment: [RuckZuck](http://ruckzuck.tools/) is a solution - all other alternatives are listed at http://alternativeto.net/software/ruckzuck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like Windows 8 [`might bring something along`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/apps) that has the same idea as an application store for Windows software

[image]

Lets just cross our fingers and hope it does not die after a year of launching and can supply decent software for all users.

There were also a few packages manager prototypes for Windows, but they never really took off, I remember hearing a lot off fuzz [win-get](http://windows-get.sourceforge.net/index.php) and how it would bring `apt-get` easiness to Windows, but visiting the page now I can see that a lot was dropped since back then and the repository has mostly outdated software.

I also found [Npackd](http://code.google.com/p/windows-package-manager/), seems decent and the repository has a couple of hundred applications.

[image]

And [Speed Install](http://speedinstall.com)

[image]

They can help you out installing Windows software and even though they might not be actual stores they are close to a package manager and installer for Windows.

Other than that there are a few known sites out there with services that might be used the same way as an application store: [allmyapps.com](http://allmyapps.com) is one of them but not really an application store as the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 2):

No, but Windows 8 will have the [Windows Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Store), something very similar. There might be similar alternatives, though, but I have never heard of one and I doubt they would be complete enough for the needs of most users.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the upcoming [Windows Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Store) on Windows 8, [allmyapps](http://allmyapps.com/) is a service that does what you're describing.